# How do I log out of Xorg?

Tags: xorg, logout

I need to troubleshoot a problem with suspend/resume. The [debugging instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend) say:

> make sure you're logged out of Xorg (or run sleep.sh with "force" argument)

How do I log out of Xorg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you don't log out of Xorg.  Xorg has no account management capabilities at all.  The wording of that document is inaccurate.  It probably really means to log out of your window manager, and exit Xorg.

In practice, this probably means killing your X display manager (xdm, kdm, or gdm).  Do this by hitting Ctrl-Alt-F1, to switch to a text console.  Then log in and issue one of the following commands (depending on which display manager you use):

```
sudo stop gdm
sudo stop kdm
sudo stop xdm
```

Comment: If killing `X` is all that is required, wouldn't `sudo killall Xorg` work?

Comment: If gdm/xdm/kdm/etc. are running, they restart Xorg when it exits, so just killing it may not be enough.